# Про TTL и туннель IPIP

Tags: linux, vpn, tunnel, ipip

Хотел запустить OSPF поверх IPIP. Но похоже тунельный драйвер копирует TTL в заголовок. Как бы ему сказать что этого делать не нужно?

Про mangle знаю - не спортивно.

Comment: как только полез задавать вопрос - нашел ответ...

Answer (score 2):

Нужно указать TTL при создании интерфейса:

```
ip tunnel add ipip-vpn1 mode ipip remote 10.0.0.107 ttl 63
```

В противном случае пакет с OSPF (ttl 1) не доходит до адресата.